# Why do I get a 32-bit overflow when compiling in 64-bit in C++?

Tags: c++, g++, integer-overflow

So, I decided to test out a new C++ turtle-style graphics library. I decided to test it out by making the fibonacci spiral. however, upon running the program, it stops in the middle. I checked what was going on, and the fibonacci value had reversed to -2147483647, as if it was compiled in 32-bit. Can someone please help? I compiled it with g++ on Windows.
Note: I was using a vector to store the values.
Here's my code:

```cpp
//Includes and namespaces
#include "Cturtle.hpp"
#include<iostream>
namespace ct = cturtle;

std::vector<long int> fibonacci = {1, 2}; //This vector stores the fib sequence
ct::TurtleScreen scr; //Create a new Screen
ct::Turtle turtle(scr); //Create a new turtle on the screen

int main() {
    turtle.speed(ct::TS_FASTEST); //Set the turtle's speed to max
    
    while(true) {
        for(int i = 0; i < fibonacci.back(); i++) {
            
            fibonacci.push_back(fibonacci.back() + fibonacci.back()-1); //Add a new value to the fibonacci vector based off the previous two
            std::cout << fibonacci.back() << '\n'; //This is here for debug
            turtle.forward(1); //Move the turtle 1 step forward
            turtle.right(90 / fibonacci.back()); //Turn according to 90 divided by the current fibonacci value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just because you compile as 64 bit does not mean that all datatypes automagically are 64bit wide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MinGW uses the MSVC-friendly LLP64 [data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).

In LLP64, `int` and `long int` are both 32 bits, regardless of platform bitness (32/64 bit).

To get a 64-bit data type, use `long long` or `int64_t`.

e.g. `std::vector<long long>`. And also here: `for(long long i = 0; ...`